# Delete request with the Rest API

Tags: rest, http-delete

I have the delete method as follows:

```
@DELETE
@Path("/abc/{id}")
  public Response deletebottle(@PathParam("id") final int id) {
  
  logger.info("Delete abc with id " +  id);
 
  Service.instance.delete(id);
 
 return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

My question is how do I write in the URL to access this resource. If I pass the following URL

`http://localhost:9999/v1/Main/abc/1`
It executed my `Get` method which is implemented with the same path and Param the only difference is the keyword `Get` and `Delete`. How do I use the `Delete` with my URL?

Comment: You need to request the url with DELETE method, with postman for example, entering the URL in your browser is always a GET request

Comment: @TZiebura So, I might have to use either insomnia or others like it?

Comment: @TZiebura Thank you

Comment: Yes, just use some software which lets you send different types of requests where you can specify METHOD, HEADERS, PARAMETERS and request content

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [TZiebura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12938938/tziebura), you can use **Postman**

Follow this video for more help

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVQayjDNgZg